# duplicate entry for key primary in mysql

Tags: mysql

table1 : bo_indexable_attribute

```
id           version          mcs         name        search_id
285           3                13         name1       16
286           3                13         name2       16
287           3                13         name3       16
```

what i want is copying the content of this table and insert it into it again but this time with different mcs column 
so my tryings is

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bo_scenario_indexable_attribute_temp (SELECT * FROM bo_scenario_indexable_attribute WHERE mcs = @sales );

UPDATE bo_scenario_indexable_attribute_temp SET mcs = @sales_master;

INSERT INTO bo_scenario_indexable_attribute SELECT * FROM  bo_scenario_indexable_attribute_temp;
```

but this gives me `Duplicate entry '285' for key 'PRIMARY'`

any suggestions ??

Comment: remove the id from inserted vales, because the id is a Primary key

Comment: If your id column is not auto-increment you must generate new values for it for every record. if it is, then just specify the column names in the insert... select statement and let the database generate new ids for you.

Comment: when i write the columns it gives me operate must be 1 column(s)

Comment: You didn't provide the structure of the source table.

Answer (score 0):

You have copied your table into temporary one by the first statement. Then by the second you do an update and in the third statament you are trying to insert into the first table the same records. Maybe your id column has unique key so you get a "duplicate entry for key primary".

Take a look here: [SQL UNIQUE Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Comment: my id is primary key auto increment

Answer (score 0):

As @Franky pointed out, your `id` column has a unique constraint. Use this:

`INSERT INTO bo_scenario_indexable_attribute SELECT version, mcs, name, search_id FROM  bo_scenario_indexable_attribute_temp;`

By leaving the `id` value out of insertion it the column will be assigned a new, unused id value which satisfies the unique constraint placed upon the column.

---

Edit based on first comment:

Use below queries:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bo_scenario_indexable_attribute_temp (SELECT version, mcs, name, search_id FROM bo_scenario_indexable_attribute WHERE mcs = @sales );

UPDATE bo_scenario_indexable_attribute_temp SET mcs = @sales_master;

INSERT INTO bo_scenario_indexable_attribute SELECT version, mcs, name, search_id FROM  bo_scenario_indexable_attribute_temp;
```

You got that error because you fetched more columns in your SELECT than you are inserting in your INSERT.

Comment: it gives me Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1